# How can I get from Nice air port to Imperia at 21:00 24/12?

Tags: france, italy, transportation, christmas

My flight arrives to Nice at 20:00 and I need to go to Imperia. All car rental services seem to be close. There is a train to Ventimiglia but that is all. How can I get from Nice air port to Imperia, Italy at 21:00 24/12 (Christmas evening) ?

Comment: Do you mean "All car rental services seem to be **close**" or ""All car rental services seem to be **closed**"?

Comment: This link https://www.nice.aeroport.fr/services/location-de-voiture seems to indicate that car rental desks at the airport are open later than 20:00 (in english https://www.nice.aeroport.fr/en/services/car-rental)

Comment: @audionuma I would double check the actual closing time on Christmas Eve by calling them directly. It is quite possible hours may be very different on that day.

Comment: @jcaron good idea. Online, it seems possible to rent a car with a pickup-time at 10 PM on december 24 at Nice airport with at least one of the rental companies. Nice is the third busiest airport in France https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_France

Answer (score 4):

The last Trenitalia train from Ventimiglia to Imperia departs at 21:20.  To catch that train, you would have to get the TER from Nice departing at 20:28 (arriving at Ventimiglia at 21:13).  This is probably implausible given a 20:00 flight arrival, particularly if you will have to deal with passport control, customs, and/or baggage claim upon your arrival in Nice.

If money is no object, and you can't find a rental car, [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Nice-Airport-NCE/Imperia) suggests hiring a towncar at a price of about 360€.  Otherwise, you may be better off getting a hotel in either Nice or Ventimiglia and completing your journey by train on Christmas morning.

Comment: If you visit relatives or friends they might be willing to get you from the airport. Otherwise a different flight might be the only sensible option.

Comment: What transport will be running on Christmas morning? In UK you could get a taxi, but the price will be loaded, and they might be fully booked.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  Trenitalia appears to be willing to sell me a ticket for any number of Ventimiglia–Imperia itineraries on 2022-12-25 for between 4.50 and 9.00 Euros.  I did find that a little surprising, though.

Comment: An alternative might be flying into Genoa airport. Perhaps it's worth remembering that many people will be travelling on Christmas Eve.

Comment: @WeatherVane France has rail service every day of the year. Service on public holidays is mostly the same as Sunday, maybe a little less but a line that has traffic on a normal Sunday would have traffic even on 25 December or 1 May. I don't know for sure about Italy, but I think it's the same. Shutting down all transportation around Christmas seems to be a UK specialty.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert the UK is notable for having virtually nothing running on Christmas Day. This is not the case in most other European countries. However I would definitely not count on a long distance taxi or private hire on Christmas Eve unless confirmed three times and with a hefty premium.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Regionale (*Veloce* or not) trains in Italy, like the ones on those lines, have fixed prices irrespective of date and time, like 99% of TERs in France. IC/FrecciaBianca (which may run on this line) don't and have dynamic pricing